# Active <nav> item not showing up on page load

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, nav

There seems to be no way I am able to get the default `<li>` element to show up in a Bootstrap-4 Nav menu.

I have both the Bootstrap css reference as well as the reference to node `jquery.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js`.

This example: https://codepen.io/jek/pen/BoWNRy works perfect. This is where i got the example from.

```
<head>
    <title>KR-DevTools</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <p></p>
    <div class='container border shadow'>
        <div class=""><h1>KR-DevTools</h1></div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div class='container border border-top-0 shadow'>

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs bordered">
            <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Session Variables</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <h3>Menu 1</h3>
                <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Menu 1</h3>
                <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Menu 2</h3>
                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Menu 3</h3>
                <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The first list item element calls the correct Bootstrap-4 classes afaik, being `<li class="nav-item active">`. The first item is meant to show up on page load but it does not.

Comment: You can have a look here http://dev.kerkradio.co.za/varcheck2.php to make it easier to see what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

**Two things:**

In your code you have `<li class="nav-item active">`. Instead, you should be making the active class on the link itself with: `<a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Session Variables</a></li>`

Secondly, change `<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">` to `<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in show active">`.

Making these changes should give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: Hey @Frank Doe, thanks for helping out! This worked perfectly and the key lies in the `<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in show active">`. Many thanks!

Comment: Great! Could you maybe accept it as the answer then? Thanks!

Comment: Don't seem to have enough reputation points yet. When I do, I will come back and accept your answer (if they allow it).